alternative to exporting instantiated class in JavaScript?
according to this Is it bad practice to export instantiated class in JavaScript?, it is not recommended to export instantiated class.
If so, I want to ask is my following implementations count as an alternative.
my class:
export default class RouterConfig{
    constructor(header = '', parameters = []){
        this.path = parameters.reduce((accumulator, current) => `${accumulator}/:${current}`, header)
    }

    path: string;

    generateURL(data = {}){
        return this.parameters.reduce((accumulator, current) => `${accumulator}/${data[current]}`, `/${this.header}`)
    }
}

so intead of exporting like so:
const route1 = new RouterConfig('abc', ['param_C', 'param_O', ])
export default route1 

does that mean i need to export it like so:

const route2 = new RouterConfig('def', ['param_G'])

export const header       = route2.header
export const parameters   = route2.parameters
export const path         = route2.path
export const generateURL  = route2.generateURL.bind(route2)


"according to this"... one user. It's your code, do what makes it easiest for you. Personally I see no issue exporting an instance of a class. It's no different to exporting an object

Yes, there’s nothing wrong with exporting a stateless instance at all.

The important part of coding and designing is to be consistent and predictable. Personally I would prefer a singleton pattern over instancing a class when the file is ”imported”, because in my option an import should not have the side effect that objects are created. But that’s just my opinion. But if you see that file as a config file then an instance can indeed be fine.

It's not bad practice to export a class instance, it will just behave like a Singleton.
Note: if you wish to stop this instance from ever being modified by any of its consumers, you can call Object.freeze on it before exporting it:
const route1 = Object.freeze(new RouterConfig('abc', ['param_C', 'param_O', ]))
export default route1 


It is a bad practice to immediately instantiate a class and then export only the instance, not the class itself - for singletons you should drop the class definition altogether and just use an object literal, or even better have multiple named exports in the module.
However, this rule does not appear to apply to your case. As far as I can tell, you have

the class in a separate module
multiple instances of the class for the different routes

so there's nothing wrong with instantiating it and then exporting those instances.

"for singletons you should drop the class definition altogether and just use an object literal". Though it may happen you want your singleton to inherit methods from a parent class. In this case I find it quite practical to do class Singleton extends MyEventTarget {} and then export const singleton = new Singleton(). Could you shed some light as to what's wrong with this pattern? I guess there is something I'm missing.

@Kaiido Why not just do export const singleton = Obect.assign(new MyEventTarget, { … })? Defining a class creates an unnecessary prototype and - possibly worse - a constructor that can be called again.

I guess that's a good solution indeed. I'm still not entirely convinced it's something that should be banned from any code base though. If one prefers the syntax allowed by  class (e.g private properties), I still think it's "valid" to use it.  It's also possibly less work when the singleton has to become an actual class when the project evolves.
